# Cannot have map type columns in DataFrame which calls set operations

Tags: hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

> : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot have map type columns in DataFrame which calls set operations(intersect, except, etc.), but the type of column map_col is map

I have a hive table with a column of type - `MAP<Float, Float>`. I get the above error when I try to do an insertion on this table in a spark context. Insertion works fine without the 'distinct'.

```
create table test_insert2(`test_col` string, `map_col` MAP<INT,INT>) 
location 's3://mybucket/test_insert2';

insert into test_insert2 
select distinct 'a' as test_col, map(0,0) as map_col
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to convert dataframe to **`.rdd`** then apply **`.distinct`** function.

***Example:***

```
spark.sql("select 'a'test_col,map(0,0)map_col 
              union all 
          select 'a'test_col,map(0,0)map_col").rdd.distinct.collect
```

***Result:***

```
Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([a,Map(0 -> 0)])
```

Comment: Why does applying `.distinct` on an RDD work but doesn't work on a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

If you can distinguish unique rows without the map (eg an ID column), you can use `dropDuplicates`.

```py
dataframe.dropDuplicates(['id'])
```