# data distribution with spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm quite new to spark SQL. I struggle to combine operations properly. What I want can be a bit tricky:

### WHAT I HAVE

From values :

```
##########
# events #
##########
#  'M'   #
#  'M'   #
#  'F'   #
#  NULL  #
##########
```

### WHAT I WANT

I'm looking for a query that can store the distribution into a map like:

```
##################
#  distribution  #
##################
#{'M': 2, 'F': 1}#
##################
```

Notice, that I don't want NULL values.

### WHAT I TRIED

I tried several SQL queries that don't works, such as:

Making a fake list `SELECT collect_list(concat(col,"\",\"",cnt)) from (SELECT col, count(col) as cnt FROM VALUES (NULL), ("M"), ("M"), ("F") AS tab(col) GROUP BY col);` => `["F","1","M","2"]`

Then pass it to the map function `Select map(mp) from (SELECT collect_list(concat(col,"\",\"",cnt)) as mp from (SELECT col, count(col) as cnt FROM VALUES (NULL), ("M"), ("M"), ("F") AS tab(col) GROUP BY col));`  => `data type mismatch`

Dear community, your help will be welcome!

PS: I want to reproduce the [histogram](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/histogram-charts.html) function of AWS Presto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the map using group by and `map_from_entries`:

```sql
select 
    map_from_entries(collect_list((events, c))) as dist 
from (
    select 
        events, 
        count(1) as c 
    from df 
    where events is not null 
    group by events
);

+----------------+
|            dist|
+----------------+
|[F -> 1, M -> 2]|
+----------------+
```

Comment: What should be the structure type? Because `StructField("dist", MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()), True)` generate the error `Cannot have map type columns in DataFrame which calls set operations` during my tests.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57170064/cannot-have-map-type-columns-in-dataframe-which-calls-set-operations). You probably called `.distinct()` in your tests. Consider using RDD like in the linked question.

Comment: I do not call distinct() either other set operations. I only use spark SQL and your answer is wrapped in a bigger request.

Comment: there are probably some set operations somewhere in the bigger request. otherwise spark would not have thrown that error.